# generate number that is not equal to the item of the arraylist

Tags: android

I am doing a project in android, my problem is, I want to generate a number that is not equal to the values from the int array, and add the generated number to the existing array.

```
int number[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Random random = new Random();
int x;

x = random.nextInt(10);
```

If `x == 6`, x will be added to the array,

If `x == 1` or `2` or equal to the values in the int array, it will generate another number until the generated number is not equal to the existing value of the array and add it.

How can I do this?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 list.add(1);
 list.add(2);
 list.add(3);

do {

Comment: im trying this in java, if ever i get my desire result im going to put this in my class on android

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 list.add(1);
 list.add(2);
 list.add(3);
        int counter = 0;

for(Integer i: list){
        System.out.println(i)
}

//output will be
//1
//2
//3

do {
counter++;
x =  ran.nextInt(20);
list.add(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void goRandom(){
x = random.nextInt(10);
check();
}
public void check(){
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
if(x != number[i]){
number.add(x);
}else{
goRandom();
}}}
```

This is my advice, but probably FD_'s advice is much better

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
x = random.nextInt(10);
while (Arrays.asList(number).contains(x)) {
     x = random.nextInt(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(8);
    arrlist.add(20);
    arrlist.add(25);
    arrlist.add(10);
    arrlist.add(15);

    Random random = new Random();
    int x;
            x = random.nextInt(10);

    boolean retval = arrlist.contains(x);
    if (retval == true) {
        System.out.println("Random number generated is available in the list. Not adding");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Random number generated is not available in the list. Adding it");
        arrlist.add(x);
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much your codes are very helpful :) 

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
     System.out.println("THANK YOU VERY MUCH :D");
}